# How to generate a list of all lists of known objects obeying some constraints

Tags: list-manipulation

Let `PlanePartitions[m_Integer]` be a certain list of objects that I'm able to produce for positive integers $m$, concretely the list of all 3d partitions of a given dimension $m$ (so object means a 3d partition).

For a fixed positive integer $n$, I'd like to build a function `f[k_]` of a positive integer $k$ that gives as output the list of *all* possible $n$-tuples $\{a_1,..a_n\}$ built out of objects $a_i \in \operatorname{PlanePartitions}[m_i]$ with the constraint that $\sum_{i=1}^n m_i = k$, including the case when some of the $a_i$ are empty objects, $a_i=\emptyset$, contributing $m_i=0$ to the sum, and considering the ordering meaningful, namely a tuple $\{...a_i,a_j...\}$ is distinct from the one with $a_i$ and $a_j$ exchanged if $a_i \neq a_j$.

Any idea how to do that?

Edit1: the function `PlanePartitions[m_Integer]` is defined in http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PlanePartition.html

Edit2: here's a first attempt, but I'm having some trouble with the empty case.

```
f[1, k_] := {#} & /@ PlanePartitions[k]
f[n_, k_] := f[n, k] = Flatten[Table[Flatten[Outer[Prepend[#2, #1] &, PlanePartitions[r], f[n - 1, k - r],1,1], 1], {r, 0, k}], 1]
```

Example: there are three 3d partitions of dimension 2 (call them $a$,$b$,$c$), one of dimension one (call it $W$), and one of dimension zero (the empty one, call it $E$); the desired function, say for $n=2$ and $k=2$, should produce a list of the form
`f[2]={{E,a},{E,b},{E,c},{a,E},{b,E},{c,E},{W,W}}}`

Comment: It's always helpful to provide a concrete, simple example.

Comment: Never use upper-case letters to name a variable—*especially* $N$, as this is a protected function in *Mathematica*.  Also, give code and examples.

Comment: @jj_p:  It is very poor style to use any upper-case-initial variable names, such as `NN` or `A`.

Comment: Did you try downloading the Mathematica notebook on the mathworld page? It contains a definition of `PlanePartitions`.

Comment: This is why I asked you to provide a concrete, simple example. Give an example input, and the desired output so that there is no confusion about what you want.

Comment: So, in terms of your problem statement, we have $m_1=2$, $m_2=1$ and $m_3=0$, with `PlanePartitions[2]` being `{a, b, c}`, `PlanePartitions[1]` being `{W}` and `PlanePartitions[0]` being `{}`?

Comment: @CarlWoll The second part is correct, the first no: since $n=2$ and $k=2$ in the example, there are only $m_1$ and $m_2$, and both can take values 0,1,2, since $m_1+m_2=k=2$.

Comment: @CarlWoll also, I denoted `PlanePartitions[0]` as `E`, not `{}`. I think to make things work it should be `E={{ }}`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would do it:

```
g[n_,k_] := With[
    {
    parts = Catenate @ Map[Permutations] @ PadRight[
        IntegerPartitions[k, n],
        {Automatic, n}
    ],
    tups = PlanePartitions /@ Range[0, k]
    },

    Catenate @ Map[Tuples[tups[[##]]]&][parts + 1]
]
```

Check with your answer:

```
PlanePartitions[k_] := PlanePartitions[k] = Array[Subsuperscript[a, k, #]&, RandomInteger[{1,4}]]

r1 = f[10,7]; //AbsoluteTiming
r2 = g[10,7]; //AbsoluteTiming

Sort@r1 == Sort@r2
```

> {6.48359, Null}
>
> {1.97131, Null}
>
> True

Comment: My attempt above works, provided one redefines `PlanePartitions[0]` as `{{{ }}}`.